# Multiple Finds and copy the result

Tags: linux, unix, find, cp

I want to find all php files from folder starting with `recup_dir` , Its working fine with following command

```
find . -type d -name "recup_dir*"  -exec find {} -name "*.php"
```

Now I want to copy found files to a directory , I searched all stackoverflow and found codes like below , but none works

```
find . -type d -name "recup_dir*"  -exec find {} -name "*.php" | xargs cp -t /var/www/vhosts/stimulatemind.com/httpdocs/backup/
```

Above code returns following error

**cp: missing file operand**

And then I tried below code , it just lists all files ,but none was copied

```
find . -type d -name "recup_dir*"  -exec find {} -name "*.php" -exec cp -rfp {} /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/backup/ \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Via ***find***'s `-path` option:

```
find -type f -path "*/recup_dir*/*.php" \
-exec cp -t /var/www/vhosts/stimulatemind.com/httpdocs/backup/ {} +
```

> **`-path pattern`**
>      File name matches shell pattern `pattern`